# get the element that triggers a javascript function

Tags: javascript

i want to know if i can access the element that triggers a function in javascript. i know... it's kinda hard to understand but maybe if you see the following code you'll get what i try to explain:

CODE HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction(this)">link</a>
```

CODE JS:

```
function myFunction(linkElement) {
   console.log(linkElement);
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but the idea is that i would like to have access to the element that triggers (or calls) the function so that the console.log would give me the 'a' element.

I know you can use an ID and send the ID to the function and easily recover the element, but it would be much nicer if i can use something more relative like the 'this' statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction(this)">link</a>
```

to this

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `event.target`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object that dispatched the event.

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Comment: It looks like this just returns the entire DOM object for me :(